# Interactive grid checkbox checked for sepecfic rows for a specific column value in oracle apex 22.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I am using an interactive grid in master-detail. In the picture below I have already saved the data whose checkbox Status column value is Y. I want that this type of rows will be selected by default. How Can I do that? Thanks in advance.
[image]